# Not getting all comments using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get comments using Facebook Graph API using this code

```
https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/comments?access_token=XXX
```

where XXX is replaced by my access token. The problem I'm facing is I'm not getting all the comments. It's end output is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0bAw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution through which I'm able to get all comments if using limit like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/comments?access_token=XXX&limit=1000
```

This solved my problem since I had only 50+ comments. Still looking for more better solution.

Comment: The “more better” solution would be to use the pagination links provided in the response.